# Regex to grab only the digits after a dollar sign

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Javascript, Is there a way to grab just the digits after a dollar sign?

Example text:

> "2000 Toyota Corolla - $1300"

I want the end result to be just `1300` not `$1300`

Comment: `/\$[\d]+/g`.. then remove `$`.

Comment: @Mr_Green - We have capturing groups for a reason..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
var str = "2000 Toyota Corolla - $1300";
var n = str.match(/\$(\d+)/);
console.log(n[1]); // 1300
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LPVy/)

Comment: Awesome! I think I was missing the entire concept of a capture group. I was grabbing the whole string and then getting the substring offset by 1 character, but this is much more efficient.

Comment: yes... n[0] will be the entire match and then n[1], n[2] etc would be each Parentheses section (if there are any)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions:

- If you want to *capture* the digits: `\$(\d+)`
- <s>If you want the whole match to only match the digits: `(?<=\$)\d+`</s> (lookbehind is unavailable in JS)

Comment: RegEx Lookbehind in JavaScript?!

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have been more clear to state that this is for JS.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should do the job:

```
/\$(\d+)/
```

Comment: why'd you need the `[^$]*` part? Just escape the dollar so it doesn't mean end of line.

Comment: @MightyPork - So true. I must have been half asleep! Tks.